# SQL Update of MD5 Passwords

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am new to PHP & SQL. I am trying to update a password from my database and I cant figure out the SQL statement so I done some research and came across this SQL statement:

```
UPDATE `Users` SET password= passwordmd5 (password)
```

I then added a bit more to the code as follows:

```
UPDATE `Users` SET password= tony123 MD5 (password) WHERE user_id = 55
```

I get the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MD5 (password) WHERE user_id = 55' at line 1
```

What do I do?

Comment: first of all, your syntax is invalid. Second, describe better what are you trying to do?

Comment: "password" as md5 is 5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99

Answer (score 40):

Correct syntax would be this:

```
UPDATE Users
SET password = MD5('tony123')
WHERE user_id = 55;
```

Or, if you were storing password in plain text and you want to convert them to hashes, do this:

```
UPDATE Users
SET password = MD5(password);
```

Comment: Thanks @sergiot, I used this `UPDATE Users SET password = MD5(password);` with slight modification for my database and it worked like a charm! This saved me from updating every record manually... :)

Comment: Small hint: If the new password (hash) is the same like the existing - the sql result will show you: `0 row will be affected` ;)

Answer (score 6):

this will work after you add db connection strings to your php file:

```
<?php
$password = 'tony123';
$passwordmd5 = md5($password);
$q = mysql_query("UPDATE `Users` SET password = '$passwordmd5' WHERE user_id = 55");
?>
```

php/mysql connection ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: I do not understand why this is voted down. This question has "php" tag and upper code solves it clearly.

Comment: stackoverflow sometimes just pisses me of! i ask a genuine quesiton here and i get voted down by some so called 'reputable users' who think they are the best at everything!!!

Answer (score 4):

i have stored password as a text into db and when i converted it to MD5 password i used this query,

```
UPDATE tablename SET columname = MD5(columname);
```

in above query you can also use any method instead of MD5 by just replacing MD5.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
UPDATE Users
SET password = PASSWORD('tony123')
WHERE user_id = 55;
```

more [info](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/change-a-password-for-mysql-on-linux-via-command-line/)